# jgoodies how to remove component added with PanelBuilder?

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

I am using [com.jgoodies.forms.builder.PanelBuilder](http://www.jaxfront.com/member/java-core-api/com/jgoodies/forms/builder/PanelBuilder.html) to add Buttons and rows. Then I call [PanelBuilder.getPanel()](http://www.jaxfront.com/member/java-core-api/com/jgoodies/forms/builder/PanelBuilder.html#getPanel()) and attach the panel to a JPopupMenu.

Is there a way to remove and reattach some of the attached components from the Panel that PanelBuilder has produced: I want to blend in/out one of the attached Buttons dynamically and the corresponding empty row (added with PanelBuilder.appendRow("f:30px")).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the component does work but it leaves area of unused space on the panel. JPanel.revalidate() works only when PanelBuilder.appendRow() was not used before adding JButton.

Also, I couldn't reattach removed JButton. It appears in the component list of JPanel but is not being displayed.

That's why I went to create a new JPanel dynamically on every request and assigning it to the JPopupMenu.

Comment: Don't forget to select one of the answers as the correct one by clicking the check beside one of these replies.

Comment: What do i do if none of the answers really solved my problem?

Comment: Mark the answer that's been most useful to you as the accepted answer.  It's valid to mark your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ketp references to the initial item, there is nothing that prevents you from doing a

```
myPanel.remove(theComponent);
```

Comment: But then the Panel's height is not updated. I see a wide empty line at the last index where the component was before. 

How do i deal with PanelBuilder.appendRow("f:30px") that was added before the Button that is needed no more after the Button is removed?

Comment: try doing panel.pack() or validate().. or have two panels in the same location and use the setvisible() method of the panel